# Trying to send and receive data using telnet in C++ but received data is truncated. Why?

Tags: c++, telnet

I'm using the follow function to send and receive data using telnet. But the received data is truncated past a few hundred characters. Why is this happening and how can I fix this? I suspect, the data is not being sent "fast enough" from the other end and my code thinks it's the end of the telnet stream. If this is the case, how can I make the receive wait long enough?

```
std::string sendTelnet(std::string str)
{
    const int default_buflen = 512;
    const char *loopback_address = "127.0.0.1";
    std::string retval;

    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                    *ptr = NULL,
                    hints;
    char recvbuf[default_buflen];
    int iResult;
    int recvbuflen = default_buflen;

    for(int i=0; i<default_buflen; i++)
    {
        recvbuf[i] = '\0';
    }

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        std::cerr<<"WSAStartup failed with error: " + iResult;
    }

    ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(loopback_address, std::to_string((long double)jtagTerminalPort).c_str(), &hints, &result);
    if ( iResult != 0 ) {
        std::cerr<<"getaddrinfo failed with error: " + iResult;
        WSACleanup();
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for(ptr=result; ptr != NULL ;ptr=ptr->ai_next) {

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, 
            ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            std::cerr<<"socket failed with error: " + WSAGetLastError();
            WSACleanup();
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        std::cerr<<"Unable to connect to server!\n";
        WSACleanup();
    }

    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send( ConnectSocket, str.c_str(), (int)strlen(str.c_str()), 0 );
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cerr<<"send failed with error: " + WSAGetLastError();
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
    }

    //telnet_bytes_sent = iResult;

    // Receive until the peer closes the connection
    do {
        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if ( iResult > 0 )
        {
            //telnet_bytes_received = iResult;
        }
    } while( iResult == 0 );

    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cerr<<"shutdown failed with error: " + WSAGetLastError();
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    retval = recvbuf;
    Sleep(100);
    return retval;
}
```

PS. What I mean by the data being truncated is that ***retval*** returns a truncated version of what is actually being sent over telnet. For example if the data sent over from the other end is "1,2,3,...,1000", by the end of the function, ***retval*** will only be holding "1,2,3,...,300".

EDIT: In application, I'm sending some commands over telnet and waiting for the response. Then, I take the received response and run some functions accordingly. Then I send the next set of commands over telnet, and wait for the response. And so on...

Comment: Re your edit, the comment in your code says that it is trying to read until the peer closes the connection, not just read a single response, and that is more or less what the code is doing, modulo bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Your do/while loop condition is wrong. It should be `while (iResult > 0)`. But you should rewrite it as a `while` loop, to avoid the double test.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Receive until the peer closes the connection
do {
    iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if ( iResult > 0 )
    {
        //telnet_bytes_received = iResult;
    }
} while( iResult == 0 );
```

This is a really convoluted way to read 512 bytes from your socket (or block forever if it's been closed).

This should look something like this:

```
// Receive until the peer closes the connection
while ((iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0)) > 0)
{
    retval.append(recvbuf, iResult);
}
```

This will read from the socket until it's closed or an error occurs, and append the received data to your return string each time through.